# Link a Material directly to an Object

Tags: python, materials

How is it possible to assign a material directly to an object using the python api, i.e. to use the same mesh linked to these object but a different material?

If I use the method obj.data.materials.new() the material is linked to the mesh and the obj.material_slots property is read only.

Has someone some advice how to accomplish that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign mat to the nth material slot on ob:

```py
ob.material_slots[n].link = 'OBJECT'
ob.material_slots[n].material = mat
```

If you want to *create* new slots, I think you should do that on the Mesh (`ob.data.materials.append(None)`).

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much for the quick and helpfull response!